# It returns undefined :( How can i get the value i want from the array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Here i have an array, im trying to get a value from it, but it returns undefined, i don't know why.

```js
var datos = [
    [['Español'][89,76,90,87]],
    [['Desarrollo Web'][94,91,90,96]],
    [['Matemáitca'][79,83,84,82]],
    [['Inglés'][87,89,93,92]],
    [['Programación'][75,73,77,71]],
    [['Seguridad Informática'][79,83,92,85]],
    [['Análisis de datos'][72,71,75,73]],
    [['Ineligencia Artificial'][80,83,80,81]],
    [['Desarrollo de Video Juegos'][88,92,94,93]],
    [['Desarrollo de aplicaciones'][92,95,96,94]]
];
console.log(datos[2][1][3]);
```

Comment: You're missing the comma between the two arrays `['Matemáitca',][79,83,84,82]`

Comment: To elaborate on what was actually happening in your code: `['Español']` was creating a one-element array, but then the list of numbers in square brackets wasn't being interpreted as an array, but as an index of the first array. So on that first line it was looking for the [element at index 87](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) in a one-element array, which of course was undefined. That's why it didn't give a syntax error when creating `datos`

Answer (score 3):

You are missing the commas between your arrays:

```js
var datos = [
    [['Español'],[89,76,90,87]],
    [['Desarrollo Web'],[94,91,90,96]],
    [['Matemáitca'],[79,83,84,82]],
    [['Inglés'],[87,89,93,92]],
    [['Programación'],[75,73,77,71]],
    [['Seguridad Informática'],[79,83,92,85]],
    [['Análisis de datos'],[72,71,75,73]],
    [['Ineligencia Artificial'],[80,83,80,81]],
    [['Desarrollo de Video Juegos'],[88,92,94,93]],
    [['Desarrollo de aplicaciones'],[92,95,96,94]]
];
console.log(datos[2][1][3]);
```